# How does ZFC account for uncountable subsets of naturals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that the set of naturals, N, exists in ZFC. And from the power set axiom, the power set of N exists. And there are uncountably many members of P(N).

But there are only countably many finite expressions of our set theoretic vocabulary. Does that mean there are members of P(N) that can't be expressed in the language of ZFC?

Specifically, if we take a random, infinite subset of N, how do we express the identity of this set in ZFC?

Comment: The axioms of set theory are just a list of what are thought to be the essential properties of things we call *sets*. From these properties, we can derive other properties of interest. I'm not sure what you mean "identifying" a set. This notion has never been formalized in any set theory AFAIK, but you can postulate the existence of a set with certain properties (your "random set?") and derive any number of other properties of such a set using these axioms. That's what we do in mathematics. What more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there *are* more sets (and even more subsets of $\Bbb N$) than can be uniquely *described* in our language.
Note that ZFC is a theory of *sets*, not a theory of *sets that we can write down and describe explicitly*.

If $A$ is a "random, infinite subset of $\Bbb N$", then there is little we know about it (for example, is $1\in A$?), but we can still be confident that, for any set $B$ with $B\ne A$, there exists an object $x$ with $(x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\notin A\land x\in B)$ to distinguish these two.

Comment: I guess my question about the random infinite subset is how we can be sure that any given infinite subset of naturals is properly a set in ZFC. As I understand it, usually if B can be defined by the axiom schema of comprehension, then we know B is properly a set in ZFC. For the case of the random infinite subset of naturals, is this a set just in virtue of its membership in the power set of naturals?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to ask:

> How does ZFC account for the uncountability of the set of all subsets of the naturals?

The answer is: very, very cleverly! In particular, rather than try to name every possible subset of the naturals, ZFC simply tells us how to reason about these subsets. For example, for each subset $A$ of the naturals, I can form the powerset $\mathcal{P}(A)$. This makes sense even if I can't name every $A$ to which this implies! Honestly, its mind-boggling how clever the whole notion of basing math on "axioms" really is.

But it gets weirder. It turns out that *if* ZFC has a model at all, then it has a countable model $\mathbf{M}$. So the element of $\mathbf{M}$ that plays the role (in $\mathbf{M}$) of the powerset of the naturals actually only has countably many elements! This is [Skolem's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem's_paradox). To resolve the paradox, note that the phrase "$X$ is countable" means: "There exists an injection $X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$." It may be the case that we have an injection $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ in the ambient universe, but $f \notin \mathbf{M}$ despite that $X \in \mathbf{M}$. In this case, $X$ may appear uncountable from the perspective of $\mathbf{M}$, despite that you and I know that in reality, it is really countable.

I guess this weirdness is essentially the price of being clever and trying to axiomatize things. But if so, it is a worthy price, since the clever idea of basing math on axioms (rather than definitions) is what makes a foundations of mathematics possible, where otherwise, it simply wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

A particularly strong instance of this is *Skolem's paradox*: even though ZFC *proves* that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there are models of ZFC containing only countably many real numbers (in fact, there are models of ZFC which are countable)!

Answer (score 0):

Expressions in set theory can be defined as sets within set theory (inductively so), but the class-sized relation "$a$ satisfies $\varphi[x]$" can't, so you can only say "there are undefinable sets" in the metalanguage.

However, if you take a model $\mathcal{M} = (M,E)$ of ZFC, then the (set-sized) relation $\{(a,\varphi[x]) \ | \ a \in M$ and $\mathcal{M} \vDash \varphi[a]\}$ is definable, hopefully. The set of integers of $\mathcal{M}$, that is $N:= \{a \in M \ | \ \mathcal{M} \vDash a$ is a finite ordinal $\}$, need not be countable, nor does $\mathcal{P}(N):=\{a \in M \ | \ \mathcal{M} \vDash \forall x(x \in a \rightarrow x \in N)\}$ need be uncountable. For instance, both can be countable, so your argument can't work in general.

For some models we have $|\mathcal{P}(N)| > |\mathbb{N}|$ so there are elements of $M$ that $\mathcal{M}$ doesn't define.

What is important is that whereas you can generally talk about "definable sets" by identifying them with their definition and then keeping in mind that different models of ZFC may have structurally different interpretations of the set that matches the definition, a set itself ("a point of the universe") doesn't have an identity - existence without essence. I personnaly merely regard the use of undefinable sets as a syntactic step encouraged by the rule in natural deduction: if $T \vdash \varphi[v]$ for some symbol $v$, then $T \vdash \forall x \varphi[x]$.